# Where can i find it("PrefName")?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, cloudrail

[image]

any idea Where i can find "PrefName"

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Also, It is better to post your code rather than providing a link, it is not common to open anonymous links.

Answer (score 0):

### Simulator

Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor, you will see this:

[image]

SharePreferences file's path is:/data/data/your_package_name/shared_prefs/your_file_name.

### Physical Device

It is same as `Simulator`. You need root your device otherwise you have no permission to see these files in your file management.

I always see it on Simulator which Api is 21, higher will also have no permission. So I suggest you create a simulator(api is 21), it will provide convenience for you test.